# QDefaultAnimationDriver timer permanently firing even if app is not visible

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Qt application where I installed an event filter on the app for debugging purposes. I noticed that even when my Qt application is hidden, the timer of  QDefaultAnimationDriver continues to fire permanently. I was under the impression that when the application is not visible, animations would be paused automatically to conserve resources.

Is it normal behavior for QDefaultAnimationDriver to permanently fire animations even when the application is not visible? If not, how can I ensure that the animations pause when the application loses visibility?